# Multer uploads only some images with React-Redux and Express

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, react-redux, multer

I'm able to upload images with multer using my POST route successfully every time no matter what image I choose. `editPost` is being called every time but will only call the my PATCH route sometimes, seemingly dependent on the image I choose but not dependent on the file's extension, size, or name.

My multer config:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
    const extension = re.exec(file.originalname)[0];
    cb(null, Date.now() + extension);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/gif') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
}

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});

module.exports = upload;
```

My route:

```
router.route('/:id')
  .patch(multerUpload.single('imageData'), async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
      const post = await Post.findById(id);
      const imageName = (req.body.imageName) ? req.body.imageName : (post.imageName ? post.imageName : null);
      const imageData = (req.file) ? req.file.path : (post.imageData ? post.imageData : null);

      return post.updateOne(
        { $set: {
          title: req.body.title,
          body: req.body.body,
          imageName: imageName,
          imageData: imageData
        }},
        { new: true },
        (err, post) => {
          if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
          return res.send(post);
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
  });
```

My action:

```
export const editPost = (id, title, body, previewText, image) =>  dispatch => {
  const formPayload = new FormData();
  formPayload.append('title', title);
  formPayload.append('body', body);
  formPayload.append('imageName', "multer-image-" + Date.now());
  formPayload.append('imageData', image);

  axios.patch(`/posts/${id}`, formPayload)
  .then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: EDIT_POST,
      payload: res.data
    }));
};
```

My repository: https://github.com/ethanwilkins/portfolio